# Getting errors while trying to output a string and set background color using TASM and DOSBox

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, emu8086, dosbox

I'm testing a TASM program to set the background color and output a string. But I'm having errors.

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    prompt db 13, 10, 'Hello Gaiz!', '$'

.code
    start:

        call color    ; Call the color procedure to set the background color
        call output

        mov ax, 4C00h  ; Exit program
        int 21h
        
output proc
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, prompt
    int 21h
    ret
output endp

color proc
    MOV AH, 06h    ; Scroll up function
    XOR AL, AL     ; Clear entire screen
    XOR CX, CX     ; Upper left corner CH=row, CL=column
    MOV DX, 184FH  ; lower right corner DH=row, DL=column 
    MOV BH, 42H   ; Red and Green
    INT 10H
    ret
color endp

end start
```

When run, random characters and not properly executed.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov ah, 09h
> lea dx, prompt
> int 21h
> ```

The pointer that you pass to DOS is actually DS:DX. Sadly, you forgot to initialize the DS segment register at program start. For this **.EXE program** using the `small` model, DS by default will be pointing at the PSP (Program Segment Prefix). Just add next to your program:

```
.code
    start:
        mov     ax, @data     ; Setup DS
        mov     ds, ax        ;
        call    color
```

### Alternatively, keep it much simpler

Start developing **.COM programs**. No troubles with setting up segment registers as they start out equal to each other (CS=DS=ES=SS):

```
  ORG 256

  call color      ; Call the color procedure to set the background color
  call output
  mov  ax, 4C00h  ; Exit program
  int  21h
        
output:
  mov  ah, 09h
  lea  dx, prompt
  int  21h
  ret

color:
  MOV  AH, 06h    ; Scroll up function
  XOR  AL, AL     ; Clear entire screen
  XOR  CX, CX     ; Upper left corner CH=row, CL=column
  MOV  DX, 184FH  ; lower right corner DH=row, DL=column 
  MOV  BH, 42H    ; Red and Green
  INT  10H
  ret

prompt db 13, 10, 'Hello Gaiz!', '$'
```